# Connecting sensor and avoiding ground loop

Tags: arduino, sensor, ground, ground-loop

I want to monitor the output from a motor encoder inside a machine, but I am worried about blowing up my Arduino.

[image]

Can I connect the outputs from the encoder directly to the input pins of the Arduino ?

Do I connect the ground from the machine to the ground on the arduino ?

Do I plug the laptop on the AC ? I am worried about creating a ground loop.

The encoder output is 5V TTL, the reference is ME22.

Comment: Put 10k resistors in series with signal 1 and signal 2

Comment: 10k or more ? Not sure I have that exact value.

Answer (score 1):

Should you decide to connect **Encoder** directly to **Arduino**, then the TTL circuit's ground would be connected to Arduino ground. This connection *might* complete a ground loop. We cannot tell if a ground loop is created, because details of the **Circuit** DC power connection to its Powerline is not shown.

One way to avoid a ground connection from **Machine** to **Arduino** is the use of two opto-isolators on `Signal_1` and `Signal_2` lines. The encoder's TTL output *should* be able to drive an opto-coupler's internal LED.
This allows both **Machine** and **Laptop** to be plugged into powerline, eliminating ground currents due to a groundloop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fti4s9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I've seen this system before. Definitely worth considering, but I would prefer something simpler if possible. What about connecting the ground from the encoder but not plugging the laptop to the main AC line ? And yes, the encoder has to stay connected to the machine, I am just trying to monitor the outputs.

Comment: Ryan, When that motor pulls heavy current from its supply, **and** when the TTL ground is tied to the motor's ground, **and** when the machine's supply is earthed, you could run into groundloop problems. An ohmmeter check between TTL DC supply (on the machine side) and powerline plug is an easy check...should be very high resistance. If this check passes, then do try a TTL-ground to Arduino ground connection - it might be noise-free.

Comment: I don't have an ohmmeter on hand, but the machine has a safety power supply to prevent people getting electrocuted touching the chassis. I think it uses a transformer. I am not worried about noise but mainly damaging my hardware, do you feel this is safe based on the info I've provided ?

Comment: I would hope that both your machine motor driver and your laptop charger would have isolated power supplies - yes a transformer should provide protection from direct damage. Andy's suggestion of adding series resistors to Arduino provides protection from transient damage. Optocouplers provides far more protection from both transients and groundloop currents. I'm guessing that your Arduino is fairly safe from blowing up, but every time you interface another item having its own power source, you're introducing chance for transient damage. Am repairing such a complex device now: has 5 DC supplies

Comment: I'm worried more about the machine I'm measuring then the arduino or even the laptop. Worst case scenario, a power transient damages the arduino, but the machine is safe even with the laptop plugged in ?

Comment: Ryan, you provide far too little info on the machine encoder's TTL 5V power supply. I can only guess if its ground is AC-line-isolated well-enough for your intended purpose.